# Vite doesn't build typescript that imported with `?url`

Tags: javascript, typescript, html5-audio, vite, audio-worklet

I'm creating an audio application with vite and typescript. I imported my audio worklet like this:

```js
import AudioMixerWorkletUrl from "./AudioMixerWorklet.ts?url";
context.audioWorklet.addModule(url);
const node = new AudioWorkletNode(context, name);
// ...
```

It works with developement server. But doesn't work with production build. The `AudioMixerWorklet.ts` was copied to `assest` folder without converting to Javascript!

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose *?worker&url* fixed this

```
import AudioMixerWorkletUrl from "./AudioMixerWorklet.ts?worker&url";
```